# Ruby Range rules with letters

Tags: ruby

When specifying a range say ('A'..'Z') you get the expected results

```
A
B
C
...
Z
```

When you specify the second charcter as lower you get the range of all lower and uppercase letters. Abbreviated ...

```
[9] pry(main)> ('A'..'z').each {|letter| puts letter}
A
B
C
...
Z
[
\
]
^
_
`
a
b
...
z
```

When I specify a range with a string using the same above premise I don't get the same result. Shouldn't a lowercase string occurred in both ranges?

```
[11] pry(main)> ('a'..'bat').include?('ace')
=> true
[12] pry(main)> ('A'..'bat').include?('ace')
=> false
```

instead I just get capitals.

```
[15] pry(main)> ('A'..'at').each {|letter| puts letter}
A
B
C
...
ZV
ZW
ZX
ZY
ZZ
=> "A".."at"
```

Comment: Why do you need to mix uppercase and lowercase?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Only because it was there to be done and I wanted to see what would happen

Comment: I asked something similar once on rubyforum.I was answered "It's just Ruby trying to be nice." which is true of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two different types of ranges.

If you ask for a range of single characters, then you get all the characters in between as  defined by the character encoding (e.g. ASCII), as you saw.  But if you ask for a range including strings that are longer than one character, then it no longer uses character set order.

What happens instead is that Ruby treats each character position as a "digit", where the set of possible digits is based on the type of character.  Letters of the alphabet are grouped by case, so an uppercase "digit" will always be uppercase throughout the range; a range that starts with all uppercase letters will never contain a lowercase letter.  Your range that starts at "A" will never get to "at", but rather than continue to infinity, Ruby stops after "ZZ" because it would have to go to three characters after that, and your specified upper limit is only two characters long.

Comment: I would have thought that a..at would have gone past ZZ back to aa. For the single characters it uses ASCII for set order, but what order is it using for strings?

Comment: I edited my answer to try and clarify.  If either end of the range has more than one character, you're out of ASCII mode and into "digit" mode, which preseves case: "A" gets incremented to "B", "C", and so on up to "Z", and then wraps around back to "A" (and increments the next digit over).  "a" gets incremented through "z" and then wraps back to "a".  "0" gets incremented through "9" and then wraps back to "0".  There's no overlap between these ranges; you'll never get from "A" to "a" or "a" to "0" or vice-versa